# Trying to fix my equation program

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple equation solver by my own that will solve problems like (3*x-4=7+2*x). The user will enter a equation and the program will split the equation to two parts, and in a loop, it will replace the x on both sides with the same numbers. The program will check if both sides of the equation are equal to each other, and print the answer. This is the script:

```
equation=input("Write an equation (variable is x): ")

side1 = equation[:equation.index("=")]

side2 = equation[equation.index("=")+1:]

for i in range(1000):
    side1=side1.replace("x", str(i+1))
    side2=side2.replace("x", str(i+1))

    if eval(side1)==eval(side2):
        print("x = %s"%i)
```

This is not my full plan of the program, I was about to upgrade it, but I found that this program doesn't work so good. When I enter an equation, the program does not print an answer, nor any error
I need to understand what are the bugs here.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, each time you call:

```
side1=side1.replace("x", str(i+1))
side2=side2.replace("x", str(i+1))
```

you are overwriting the original side variables. So the next time the loop runs, when it goes to replace 'x' in the string, there's no longer any 'x' character. The replacement will happen exactly once.

Ex.

```
# Beginning of Iter 1:
side1 = 3*x-4

# Beginning of Iter 2:
side1 = 3*1-4

# no longer any 'x' left to replace
```

What you should do instead, is use different temporary variables for your altered version of `side1` and `side2`.

*Edit*

**Other Problems with Your Snippet:**

The last line should read `print("x = %s" % (i+1))` since you use `i+1` in your replacements. Otherwise, when the equation is solved for ex using `x=11`, then it will print `x=10`.

If instead you don't want to worry about when you need `i + 1` vs `i`, you can just alter your range call to `range(1,1000)` -- that way it starts with `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`

Comment: Is there a way that i can pass that x loop?

Comment: Use the suggestion at the bottom of my post: name your altered variables something different.

Comment: Also added an explanation of another bug.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to write this, I understand you, but I don't know how to write this  down. It's a lot to ask, but can you show a full script of your answer? Anyways, thanks

Comment: All I was saying was rename the variables inside the loop. Example: `alt1=side1.replace("x", str(i+1))`